# How to improve css animations performance

Tags: html, css

I just want to ask is there any plugin or add-on (`<link src="SomePliginURL">`) to improve the website performing in animations and stop the lag when I do multiple animations on one time.
NOTE: some of my website animations are used from this link: https://www.theappguruz.com/tag-tools/web/CSSAnimations/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your website is not performing when you are using multiple animations with your library, use [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) instead which is very powerfull and lightweight.

```
    <link href="assets/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
```